# How to set PortalFolder when publishing via arcpy.sharing?

Tags: python, arcpy

I am using the example here to publish map image layers with associated feature layers from an EGDB to ArcGIS Enterprise. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.9/arcpy/sharing/mapimagesharingdraft-class.htm#GUID-98B8320E-3561-4E46-AECF-70B0553AE4FF

The only change from the example is I've set the portalFolder property in line 87 to an existing folder in my Portal but the services get placed in my root Portal Folder. How do I publish my services to the specified Portal Folder rather than the root folder?

```
import arcpy
import os
import xml.dom.minidom as DOM

def configure_featureserver_capabilities(sddraftPath, capabilities):
    """Function to configure FeatureServer properties"""
    # Read the .sddraft file
    doc = DOM.parse(sddraftPath)

    # Find all elements named TypeName
    # This is where the additional layers and capabilities are defined
    typeNames = doc.getElementsByTagName('TypeName')
    for typeName in typeNames:
        # Get the TypeName to enable
        if typeName.firstChild.data == "FeatureServer":
            extension = typeName.parentNode
            for extElement in extension.childNodes:
                if extElement.tagName == 'Info':
                    for propSet in extElement.childNodes:
                        for prop in propSet.childNodes:
                            for prop1 in prop.childNodes:
                                if prop1.tagName == "Key":
                                    if prop1.firstChild.data == 'WebCapabilities':
                                        if prop1.nextSibling.hasChildNodes():
                                            prop1.nextSibling.firstChild.data = capabilities
                                        else:
                                            txt = doc.createTextNode(capabilities)
                                            prop1.nextSibling.appendChild(txt)
    # Write to the .sddraft file
    f = open(sddraftPath, 'w')
    doc.writexml(f)
    f.close()

def configure_mapserver_capabilities(sddraftPath, capabilities):
    """Function to configure MapServer properties"""
    # Read the .sddraft file
    doc = DOM.parse(sddraftPath)

    # Find all elements named TypeName
    # This is where the additional layers and capabilities are defined
    typeNames = doc.getElementsByTagName('TypeName')
    for typeName in typeNames:
        # Get the TypeName to enable
        if typeName.firstChild.data == "MapServer":
            extension = typeName.parentNode
            for extElement in extension.childNodes:
                if extElement.tagName == 'Definition':
                    for propArray in extElement.childNodes:
                        if propArray.tagName == 'Info':
                            for propSet in propArray.childNodes:
                                for prop in propSet.childNodes:
                                    for prop1 in prop.childNodes:
                                        if prop1.tagName == "Key":
                                            if prop1.firstChild.data == 'WebCapabilities':
                                                if prop1.nextSibling.hasChildNodes():
                                                    prop1.nextSibling.firstChild.data = capabilities
                                                else:
                                                    txt = doc.createTextNode(capabilities)
                                                    prop1.nextSibling.appendChild(txt)
    # Write to the .sddraft file
    f = open(sddraftPath, 'w')
    doc.writexml(f)
    f.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Sign in to portal
    arcpy.SignInToPortal("https://www.portal.domain.com/webadaptor", "MyUserName", "MyPassword")

    # Set output file names
    outdir = r"C:\Project\Output"
    service_name = "MapImageSharingDraftExample"
    sddraft_filename = service_name + ".sddraft"
    sddraft_output_filename = os.path.join(outdir, sddraft_filename)
    sd_filename = service_name + ".sd"
    sd_output_filename = os.path.join(outdir, sd_filename)

    # Reference map to publish
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"C:\Project\World.aprx")
    m = aprx.listMaps('World')[0]

    # Create MapImageSharingDraft and set copyDataToServer property to False to reference registered data
    server_type = "FEDERATED_SERVER"
    federated_server_url = "https://MyFederatedServer.esri.com/server"
    sddraft = m.getWebLayerSharingDraft(server_type, "MAP_IMAGE", service_name)
    sddraft.federatedServerUrl = federated_server_url
    sddraft.copyDataToServer = False
    sddraft.portalFolder = 'Test_Folder'

    # Create Service Definition Draft file
    sddraft.exportToSDDraft(sddraft_output_filename)

    """Modify the .sddraft file to include a feature layer and set map image layer and feature layer properties"""

    # Modify the .sddraft file to change map image layer properties
    # Defaults are Map,Query,Data
    # Comment out the line below if you do not want to modify map image layer properties
    configure_mapserver_capabilities(sddraft_output_filename, "Map,Data")

    # Modify the .sddraft file to include a feature layer
    # Read the file
    doc = DOM.parse(sddraft_output_filename)

    # Find all elements named TypeName
    # This is where the extensions are defined
    typeNames = doc.getElementsByTagName('TypeName')
    for typeName in typeNames:
        # Get the TypeName to enable
        if typeName.firstChild.data == "FeatureServer":
            extension = typeName.parentNode
            for extElement in extension.childNodes:
                # Include a feature layer
                if extElement.tagName == 'Enabled':
                    extElement.firstChild.data = 'true'

    # Write to new .sddraft file
    sddraft_mod_xml = service_name + '_mod_xml' + '.sddraft'
    sddraft_mod_xml_file = os.path.join(outdir, sddraft_mod_xml)
    f = open(sddraft_mod_xml_file, 'w')
    doc.writexml(f)
    f.close()

    # Modify the .sddraft file to change feature layer properties
    # Defaults are Query,Create,Update,Delete,Uploads,Editing
    # Comment out the line below if you don't want to modify feature layer properties
    configure_featureserver_capabilities(sddraft_mod_xml_file, "Create,Sync,Query")

    # Stage Service
    print("Start Staging")
    arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft_mod_xml_file, sd_output_filename)

    # Share to portal
    print("Start Uploading")
    arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd_output_filename, federated_server_url)

    print("Finish Publishing")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portalFolder property only works if the data is hosted. In my case, I am publishing services from a registered data store (enterprise geodatabase).

The best solution I could come up with is to create the Portal folder and move my newly published services into the folder.

```
portalFolder = 'new_folder'

# Create a new folder
gis.content.create_folder(portalFolder, owner=user)
portalFolder = str(newFolder['title'])

# Search for the newly published services and move them to the new portal folder
searchData = gis.content.search(query='title:{}'.format(service_name))  # Get all items with the service name
if len(searchData) > 0:
    arcpy.AddMessage('Moving items...')
    for item in searchData:
        myItem = item.id
        itemToMove = gis.content.get(myItem) 
        itemToMove.move(portalFolder)
```